# Reproducing drag-n-drop for Feature Classes using ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, linear-referencing, feature-dataset

There is a Geodatabase with several Feature Datasets (FD), because a [requirement](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pipeline-referencing-blog/lrs-information-model-update/ba-p/895432) in Location referencing tools in ArcGIS Pro 2.6 and above, Feature Classes (FC) from one FD should be moved to another FD.

I have found several answers, like:

- https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/move-feature-class-from-dataset-a-to-dataset-b-in-database/m-p/1025627#M59896
- https://community.esri.com/t5/data-management-questions/move-feature-classes-out-of-feature-dataset/td-p/163438
- [Using ArcPy to Move Feature Classes to Feature Dataset?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317792/using-arcpy-to-move-feature-classes-to-feature-dataset)

The answers can be summarized on:

1. Drag-n-Drop from one FD to another FD
2. Programmatically (Python) copy, delete, rename the FC using either:

   a. `CopyFeatures_management`

   b. `FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion`

This two programmatically options, sounds good from the point of view of the structure and content of the FC. But the underlying process is not the same as the option 1.

I moved a FC using Drag-n-Drop from the FD Integrity_Pub to Integrity:
[image]

Properties before moving the FC:

[image]

Properties after moving the FC:
[image]

When the FC is moved using the Option 2.b. (it is recommended [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317792/using-arcpy-to-move-feature-classes-to-feature-dataset)):

[image]

Is there a way to move the FC, programmatically and keep the Archiving and Versioning? Like the Drag-n-Drop does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, after taking this question directly to Esri, The answer is:

> No, there is no way to programmatically replicate the same behavior with drag-n-drop.